# Unexpected image blurring

Tags: html, css

I have a WordPress site, which has an issue with the logo. 
If you'll view it on a desktop(not retina),
it will be blurred after load BUT after scaling-up and scaling back its appearance becomes normal. 
The source image height is 100, and  height is 50, so why does it gets blurred?

Comment: How much value is this question - as it is worded now - going to have in 5 years? Are you sure the content of the link you provided is not going to ever change? Getting an answer to the question you have is just one, and not even the main point of StackOverflow.

Comment: Agree. Updated the post.

Comment: The OP has removed the link to original website where problem exists. Taking undue advantage of platform and waste of people's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the original image resolution that create this.

Optimising your picture for the actual size would solve your problem I believe or setting the custom CSS to the following (with the current image size):

```
.nm-header-logo img {
    height: 51px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When an image is bigger than what you set it for 50px the browser shrinks the images to that size. In a lot of cases the result is not good and it may even be worse in some browsers (e.g. Chrome). You end up with blurry or jagged edges. Since you still need retina support you should try using 2 images, a smaller one that has 50px height that will load for non retina and one for retina which is twice as big. You have to modify the code for that:

You can [use this method here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

E.g.

```
<img srcset="logo-twice-as-big.jpg 2x"
     src="logo-normal-size.jpg" alt="Logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this property to your image.

```
.nm-header-logo img {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

The image-rendering property defines how the browser should render an image if it is scaled up or down from its original dimensions.

> The possible values are : auto | crisp-edges | pixelated

`pixelated`: as the image changes size the browser will preserve its pixelated style by using nearest-neighbour scaling. This value only applies to images that are scaled up.

Comment: Didn’t work. Blur have gone, but the rendered image looks much worse than original.